# How to project addresses on a British National Grid map in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have a couple of maps on which I need to project a list of addresses. The problem is that the two maps are in "The Ordnance Survey National Grid reference system" i.e. "British National Grid".

If I project the long/lat of the addresses, obviously, they are not projected in the right spot. I tried a lot of things but I was not able to solve the problem.

Any suggestion?

I'm open either on transforming the long/lat in something else or transforming the maps.

EDIT: Let's say that I have one map and this map is a shapefile. I wrote that they are not correct because if I have a portion of map of one city (for example London) and I project the long/lat of an address located in London, in ArcGIS the point will be displayed far from the map. In order to project it I used the standard procedure of "display x-y data".

EDIT2: Sorry for the problems, but I'm not really an expert of Gis. I don't know if it is possible to put the URL of the map here, but basically I'm using the  Land Registry's INSPIRE Index Polygons

EDIT3: the original file is in the GML format. I first tranform it in a shapefile then, when I import it in ArcGis, the program automatically recognize it with the Projected Coordinate System: OSGB_1936_British_National_Grid

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  Unfortunately, the meaning of "couple of maps" is unclear.  Are they images? Why are lon/lat values "obviously" not projected correctly?  What have you attempted to project them?  What exact things have you tried, and how, *exactly* did they not work?  Please **edit the question** to clarify these things.

Comment: The problem here is the meaning of "map" -- generally it refers to a finished cartographic product. A map can't be a shapefile, which is a data storage format, many of which are usually needed to make a map.  There are two basic methods utilized for data projection -- One is used when you have data in a known projection and wish to copy it to a new data file in a different projection, and the other is to correctly define a data file with an unknown coordinate system, so that that ArcMap can project "on the fly" into the coordinate system defined by the map canvas.  Which have you used?